# Avoiding Java stream repeated code using lambdas

Tags: java, lambda

This is the code for adding addon product to carts. Suppose the cart has a cake so a candle would be an addon. I see this `addonCart.getItems().stream().findFirst().get()` repeated and want to use this once among other usages.

Also how do I remove this declaration of exception:
`catch (UnsupportedOperationException e)`

*Adding addon products to cart*

```
public String addAddonToCart(final Cart addonCart) {
        log.info("Start : addAddonToCart method started");
        final var cart = this.cartRepository.findById(addonCart.getId()).map(e -> e).orElseThrow(() -> {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException(new ErrorInfo(ErrorConstants.CART_NOT_FOUND));
        });
        final var items = cart.getItems().stream().map(item -> {
            if (item.getItemId().equals(addonCart.getItems().stream().findFirst().get().getItemId())) {
                if (Objects.isNull(item.getAddOns())) {
                    item.setAddOns(addonCart.getItems().stream().findFirst().get().getAddOns());
                } else {
                    try {
                        item.getAddOns().addAll(addonCart.getItems().stream().findFirst().get().getAddOns());
                    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
            return item;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        cart.setItems(items);
        this.cartRepository.save(cart);
        log.info("End : addAddonToCart method ended");
        return Constants.CART_ADDON_ADDED_SUCCESSFULLY;
    }
```

*Delete item from cart*

```
/**
     * Delete product from cart.
     *
     * @param itemId the item id
     * @return the string
     */
    public String deleteProductFromCart(final String itemId) {
        log.info("Start : deleteProductFromCart method started");
        final var cart = this.cartRepository.findByItemsItemId(itemId);
        if (cart.isPresent()) {
            final var itemList = cart.get().getItems().stream().filter(item -> {
                return !item.getItemId().equals(itemId);
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
            cart.get().setItems(itemList);
            this.cartRepository.save(cart.get());
        } else {
            log.info("End : deleteProductFromCart method ended");
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException(new ErrorInfo(ErrorConstants.PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND));
        }
        log.info("End : deleteProductFromCart method ended");
        return Constants.CART_ITEM_DELETE_SUCCESSFULLY;
    }
```

*Delete addon from cart*

```
public String deleteAddonFromCart(Cart addonCart) {
        log.info("Start : deleteAddonFromCart method started");
        final var itemId = addonCart.getItems().stream().findFirst().get().getItemId();
        final var addonId = addonCart.getItems().stream().findFirst().get().getAddOns().stream().findFirst().get()
                .getProductId();
        final var cart = this.cartRepository.findByItemsItemId(itemId).map(e -> e).orElseThrow(() -> {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException(new ErrorInfo(ErrorConstants.CART_NOT_FOUND));
        });
        final var items = cart.getItems().stream().filter(item -> item.getItemId().equals(itemId)).map(item -> {
            try {
                item.getAddOns().removeIf(addon -> addon.getProductId().equals(addonId));
            } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
            }
            return item;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        try {
            cart.getItems().removeIf(item -> item.getItemId().equals(itemId));
            cart.getItems().addAll(items);
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
        }
        this.cartRepository.save(cart);
        log.info("Start : deleteAddonFromCart method ended");
        return Constants.CART_ADDON_DELETED_SUCCESSFULLY;
    }
```

**Cart Entity**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document("cart")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Cart extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** The id. */
    @NotNull(message = "cartId can not be null", groups = { CartViews.AddonAddView.class })
    @NotBlank(message = "cartId can not be blank", groups = { CartViews.AddonAddView.class })
    @Id
    @JsonView({ CartViews.AddonAddView.class })
    private String id;

    /** The domain id. */
    private String domainId;

    /** The checkout id. */
    private String checkoutId;

    /** The user IP. */
    private String userIP;

    /** The agents. */
    @JsonProperty("agents")
    private List<Agent> agents;

    /** The customer party id. */
    // @JsonView({ CartViews.AddItemDetailsView.class })
    private String customerPartyId;

    /** The guuid. */
    // @JsonView({ CartViews.AddItemDetailsView.class })
    private String guuid;

    /** The sender. */
    @JsonProperty("sender")
    private Sender sender;

    /** The channel id. */
    @NotNull(message = "channelId can not be null", groups = { CartViews.AddItemDetailsView.class })
    @NotBlank(message = "channelId can not be blank", groups = { CartViews.AddItemDetailsView.class })
    @JsonView({ CartViews.AddItemDetailsView.class })
    private String channelId;

    /** The action. */
    private String action;

    /** The reason id. */
    private String reasonId;

    /** The sub reason id. */
    private String subReasonId;

    /** The comments. */
    private String comments;

    /** The cart total. */
    private Float cartTotal;

    /** The tax included in cart total. */
    private Float taxIncludedInCartTotal;

    /** The tax on cart total. */
    private Float taxOnCartTotal;

    /** The adjustment. */
    @JsonProperty("adjustment")
    private List<Adjustment> adjustment;

    /** The status. */
    private String status;

    /** The items. */
    @Valid
    @NotNull(message = "items can not be null", groups = { CartViews.AddItemDetailsView.class,
            CartViews.AddonDeleteView.class, CartViews.AddonAddView.class })
    @JsonProperty("items")
    @JsonView({ CartViews.AddItemDetailsView.class, CartViews.AddonDeleteView.class, CartViews.AddonAddView.class })
    private List<Item> items;

}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Comment: Please include the documented interface for `Cart`.

Comment: Added Cart entity

Comment: does your code work as you intended?

Answer (score 2):

Initial impressions:

```
public String addAddonToCart(final Cart addonCart) {
        log.info("Start : addAddonToCart method started");
        final var cart = this.cartRepository.findById(addonCart.getId())
                .map(e -> e) // why
                .orElseThrow(() -> {
                        throw new ResourceNotFoundException(new ErrorInfo(ErrorConstants.CART_NOT_FOUND)); // this can be extracted
                });

        final var items = cart.getItems().stream()
                 // map is not appropriate for what you are doing
                .map(item -> {
                        // holy sausage conditionals
                        if (item.getItemId().equals(addonCart.getItems().stream().findFirst().get().getItemId())) {
                                if (Objects.isNull(item.getAddOns())) {
                    item.setAddOns(addonCart.getItems().stream().findFirst().get().getAddOns());
                                } else {
                                        try {
                        item.getAddOns().addAll(addonCart.getItems().stream().findFirst().get().getAddOns());
                                        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
                                }
                        }
                }
            return item;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        cart.setItems(items);
        this.cartRepository.save(cart);
        log.info("End : addAddonToCart method ended");
        return Constants.CART_ADDON_ADDED_SUCCESSFULLY; // Why are you returning statuses? This method should be a void.
    }
```

Most of the refactoring is done by avoiding streams and using meaningful variables instead:

```
    public void addAddonToCart(final Cart addonCart) {
        log.info("Start : addAddonToCart method started");
        final var cart = this.cartRepository.findById(addonCart.getId())
            .orElseThrow(CartNotFound::new);

        for(var item : cart.getItems()) {
            if (item.getItemId().equals(addonCart.getItems().get(0).getItemId())) {
                if (Objects.isNull(item.getAddOns())) {
                    item.setAddOns(addonCart.getItems().get(0).getAddOns());
                } else {
                    item.getAddOns()
                         .addAll(addonCart.getItems().get(0).getAddOns());
                }
            }
        }

        this.cartRepository.save(cart);
        log.info("End : addAddonToCart method ended");
    }

    private static class CartNotFound extends ResourceNotFoundException {
        public CartNotFound() {
            super(new ErrorInfo(ErrorConstants.CART_NOT_FOUND))
        }
    }
```

But this whole method definition is "wrong" and is making you jump through the hoops. You are adding addons to the cart meaning this:

```
    public void addAddonToCart(final cartId, final itemId, final List<Addon> addons) {
        log.info("Start : addAddonToCart method started");
        final var cart = this.cartRepository.findById(cartId)
            .orElseThrow(CartNotFound::new);

        for(var item : cart.getItems()) {
            if (item.getItemId().equals(itemId)) {
                if (Objects.isNull(item.getAddOns())) {
                    item.setAddOns(addons);
                } else {
                    item.getAddOns().addAll(addons);
                }
            }
        }

        this.cartRepository.save(cart);
        log.info("End : addAddonToCart method ended");
    }
```

You can make the code even cleaner by having item addons set from the beginning.

```
    public void addAddonToCart(final cartId, final itemId, final List<Addon> addons) {
        log.info("Start : addAddonToCart method started");
        final var cart = this.cartRepository.findById(cartId)
            .orElseThrow(CartNotFound::new); // why are you searching for a cart here?

        for(var item : cart.getItems()) {
            if (item.getItemId().equals(itemId)) {
                item.getAddOns().addAll(addons); // now, this is stinky
                break;
            }
        }

        this.cartRepository.save(cart);
        log.info("End : addAddonToCart method ended");
    }
```

`addAddOns` should be a method on the item. Finding the correct cart should also be separate.

```
    public Cart findById(String cartId) {
        return this.cartRepository.findById(cartId)
           .orElseThrow(CartNotFound::new);
    }

    public void addAddonToItem(final String cartId, final String itemId, final List<Addon> addons) {
        log.info("Start : addAddonToCart method started");
        final var cart = findById(cartId);

        for(var item : cart.getItems()) {
            if (item.getItemId().equals(itemId)) {
                item.addAddOns(addons);
                break;
            }
        }

        this.cartRepository.save(cart);
        log.info("End : addAddonToCart method ended");
    }
```

Same thing happens in the delete method:

```
public Cart findByItemId(String itemId) {
    return this.cartRepository.findByItemId(itemId)
        .orElseThrow(CartNotFound::new);
}

    public void deleteAddonFromCart(final String itemId, String addonId){
        log.info("Start : deleteAddonFromCart method started");
        final var cart = findByItemId(itemId);

        final Optional<Item> item = cart.getItem(itemId);
        
        item.ifPresent(item -> item.removeAddon(addonId));

        this.cartRepository.save(cart);
        log.info("Start : deleteAddonFromCart method ended");
    }

...

in cart entity
class Cart ... {
    ...
    public Optional<Item> getItem(String itemId) {
        return this.items.stream()
            .filter(item -> item.getItemId().equals(itemId)
            .findAny();
    }
}

...

in item entity
class Item {
    ...
    public void removeAddon(String addonId) {
         this.addons.removeIf(addon -> addon.getProductId().equals(addonId));
    }
}
```

You can even introduce some more errors if you want:

```
    public void deleteAddonFromCart(final String itemId, String addonId){
        log.info("Start : deleteAddonFromCart method started");
        final var cart = findByItemId(itemId);

        cart.getItem(itemId)
            .orElseThrow(ItemNotFound::new)
            .removeAddon(addonId);

        this.cartRepository.save(cart);
        log.info("Start : deleteAddonFromCart method ended");
    }
```

With additional methods we can even refactor the addon addition:

```
    public void addAddonToItem(final String cartId, final String itemId, final List<Addon> addons) {
        log.info("Start : addAddonToCart method started");
        final var cart = findById(cartId);

        cart.getItem(itemId)
            // .orElseThrow(ItemNotFound::new)
            // .addAddOns(addons)
            .ifPresent(item -> item.addAddOns(addons));

        this.cartRepository.save(cart);
        log.info("End : addAddonToCart method ended");
    }
```